# How to trigger a method invocation of an activity from another activity?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bitmap, kotlin

I have a `CropViewActivity` that crops an image, saves the cropped image to the external storage. The process of decoding the bitmap and saving it to external storage is done in another thread. So the crop activity finishes, while the image processing still goes on in the background. Now I want a way to inform my other `Activity`, which contains an `ImageView`. At the end of the image processing in the background, the `ImageView` should then fetch the saved image from memory and load it.

How to achieve this inter-thread cum inter-activity communication? Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing that. I would like to refer you some.

1. You might consider using `BroadcastReceiver` when you are finished processing your image. You need to register the receiver in your activity which contains the `ImageView` and after processing the image in another activity, send the broadcast with the desired intent that you are listening to receive. Here's a [sample implementation](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) on how you can implement a `BroadcastReceiver`.
2. Another way of communicating between activities is starting an activity for a result. See [developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) to see how you can use `startActivityForResult` and then get the result from the activity which is processing the image and getting the result back to the calling activity which contains the `ImageView` in your case.

You might pick any of these two which is best suited according to your use-case. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks alot :) The BroadcastReceiver method worked for me.

Comment: Sorry. I've corrected it. I am new to stackoverflow. I wasn't sure what that tick icon was for.

Answer (score 0):

AsnycTask?

```
typealias Callback = () -> Unit

class BitmapWorker: AsyncTask<Callback, Void, Callback?>
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Callback): Callback? {
        // work with bitmap
        return params.firstOrNull()
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(finishTask: Callback?) {
        finishTask?.invoke()
    }
}
```

Call this like:

```
BitmapWorker().execute(fun() {
    println("finished")
}
```

Comment: I had to research a lot about `AsyncTask` before it got my work done. Thank you for the suggestion :) This method seemed the most elegant to me.